# Why is the property "dadType" being set to all the options avalable and staying with the last one, rather than the one selected?

Tags: javascript, properties

It's basicaly a text based adventure game I thought would be a fun first project.

Game.js

```js
const textElement = document.getElementById('text')
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById('option-buttons')

let factions =["Grill Dad","Sports Dad","Car Dad","Vacation Dad","Drama Dad","The Craft Dad"]
let state = {
  dadType : '',
  items : ''
}
//variables
function startGame() {
  state = {}
  showTextNode(1)
}
//make a function to show the first prompt and reset "state"
function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
  const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
  textElement.innerText = textNode.text
  while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }
//function to remove options with no text
  textNode.options.forEach(option => {
    if (showOption(option)) {
      const button = document.createElement('button')
      button.innerText = option.text
      button.classList.add('btn')
      button.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption(option))
      optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    }
  })
}
//function to add options till you run out
function showOption(option) {
  return option.requiredState == null || option.requiredState(state)
}
//function to check for "state"
function selectOption(option) {
  const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
  if (nextTextNodeId <= 0) {
    return startGame()
  }
  state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
  showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}
//function to advance to the next prompt and assign "state"
/*function randNum() {
let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
}
//random generator
function getDadType(state){
  return state.dadType
}
//get dad type (not working)
*/
const textNodes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Insert adventure description here pick a faction of dad to play as.',
    options: [
      {
        text: factions[0],
        setState: state = {dadType: 'grill dad'} ,
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: factions[1],
        setState: state = {dadType: 'sports dad'},
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: factions[2],
        setState: state = {dadType: 'car dad'},
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: factions[3],
        setState: state = {dadType: 'vacation dad'},
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: factions[4],
        setState: state = {dadType: 'drama dad'},
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: factions[5],
        setState: state = {dadType: 'craft dad'},
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: 'Placeholder for Random',
        setState: {},
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: 'Placeholder for Back',
        nextText: 2
      }
     ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "First part of backstory "+state.dadType,
    options:[
    {
      text: 'some things you could say',
      nextText: 1
    }
startGame()
```

The property "dadType" is supposed to be set to whatever `dadtype` you selected in the first text node, but rather than setting it, and then ignoring the rest of the option buttons, it seems to run through all the options. I want it to just set the last ones property. It will still go to the correct next window, but the correct property is not set.

Comment: I have written an answer for you, identifying your problem and it also contains a proposed solution, however, if this is not enough, then you will need to create a minimal, reproducible example, preferrably as a snippet in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating functions that set the state, you are actually setting the state upon each option. Your code

```
options: [
  {
    text: factions[0],
    setState: state = {dadType: 'grill dad'} ,
    nextText: 2
  },
  {
    text: factions[1],
    setState: state = {dadType: 'sports dad'},
    nextText: 2
  },
  {
    text: factions[2],
    setState: state = {dadType: 'car dad'},
    nextText: 2
  },
  {
    text: factions[3],
    setState: state = {dadType: 'vacation dad'},
    nextText: 2
  },
  {
    text: factions[4],
    setState: state = {dadType: 'drama dad'},
    nextText: 2
  },
  {
    text: factions[5],
    setState: state = {dadType: 'craft dad'},
    nextText: 2
  },
  {
    text: 'Placeholder for Random',
    setState: {},
    nextText: 2
  },
  {
    text: 'Placeholder for Back',
    nextText: 2
  }
 ]
```

evaluates each object and initializes a `setState` member to the result of the assignment of a `dadtype` object to `state`. However, each time your assignment operation evaluates, `state` is modified as a side-effect.

So, instead of

```
setState: state = {dadType: 'grill dad'}
```

you will need to use something like

```
setState: function() {
    state = {dadType: 'grill dad'};
}
```

this is a function that sets the `state` to an object once it is called instead of modifying the state upon initialization.